# How to create spatial tag clouds or "tag maps"?

Tags: web-mapping, visualisation

I'm looking for implementations of spatial tag clouds or "tag maps". Some papers I found talk about a Yahoo Tag Maps API, but I couldn't find any such thing.

I'd prefer OpenLayers-based solutions, but others would be interesting too.

Edit: Example images can be found at http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~sbbb717/go2/iv_figs/, e.g:

[image]

Comment: could you post an example/link of such a map?

Comment: One of the guys here at Esri Australia created one for geotagging #tags on twitter. Unfortunately was a WPF app which only ran on the desktop. I could ask him to put it out

Answer (score 6):

The key paper describing this work is Interactive Tag Maps and Tag Clouds for the Multiscale Exploration of Large Spatio-temporal Datasets, by: Aidan Slingsby, Jason Dykes, Jo Wood, Keith Clarke, In IV '07: Proceedings of the 11th International Conference Information Visualization (2007), pp. 497-504. doi:10.1109/IV.2007.71 http://www.citeulike.org/user/ianturton/article/2040316. However I can't find a reference to the actual tag-map applet they used in the paper (and I think I pointed that out when I reviewed the paper, so much for peer-review).

Comment: Thanks iant, that's the paper mentioning Yahoo Tag Maps API if I'm not mistaken. Reference #11 should have linked to the Yahoo developer page of the API, but it doesn't exist (any more?).

Comment: Looks like it is now closed (http://developer.yahoo.com/search/content/V1/termExtraction.html)

Answer (score 4):

http://kelsocartography.com/blog/?p=2490

working example
http://www.net-lettings.co.uk/london-estate-agents-areas1.aspx

Comment: Thanks Mapperz, but these don't look quite right ... I'd expect differently sized labels depending on how many same-tagged features are found in close proximity.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the things we talk about in HEALTH GeoJunction: place-time-concept browsing of health publications http://www.ij-healthgeographics.com/content/9/1/23 could be relevant. We didn't put the tags on the map but we do discuss how to build a tag cloud with spatial aspects.

The actual app is at http://www.apps.geovista.psu.edu/hgj/# (but you will need flash enabled).

Comment: I keep getting a 'No data returned' error in the flash app.

Comment: Sorry about that the database password had expired which took some tracking down.

Answer (score 2):

This is Yahoo's Flash-based solution: http://tagmaps.research.yahoo.com/worldexplorer.php

Too bad, the [API link](http://developer.yahoo.com/yrb/tagmaps/) is broken.