# Fitting a word/tag cloud into geographic boundaries

Tags: visualisation, cartography

Are there any available tools or a recommend methods for displaying a tag or word cloud (also know as [wordle](http://www.wordle.net/)) onto a world map, much like in this example: [Map: United States of surnames](http://flowingdata.com/2011/01/27/map-united-states-of-surnames/)? (There may be other examples on the NY Times.)

Note that that in the example above, word are located by fixed coordinates, whereas text clouding might be implemented with the wordle algorithm (as [described on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342687/algorithm-to-implement-something-like-wordle)) in an automatic manner. So, is there a software that let you put words at random on a given country, or do you think it's best to tweak the wordle original algorithm (e.g., by adding constraints based on predefined frontiers)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [spatial tag clouds - "tag maps"](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4366/spatial-tag-clouds-tag-maps)

Comment: @underdark Thanks for pointing out that thread. However, it seems to me more related to geotagging, whereas I am looking for a solution where we don't have to associate known spatial coordinates (e.g., town or counties) to each word. In other words, let the layout of words into a country be free of constraints other than its actual frontiers. If others feel it is really a duplicate, I can remove it without any prob.

Comment: @chl: So the location of words inside the boundaries has no meaning? Then it's no duplicate.

Comment: @underdark Yes, exactly. The main idea of wordle is trying to find a good-looking spatial layout with words sized by their relative frequencies. Then, I just want to constraint the choice of possible (x,y) coordinates on the "borders".

Comment: There are a few tag/cloud threads here in GSE. http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=tag+cloud It seems that there should be some effort (perhaps initiated by the stack exchange community) to differentiate cloud from tag/cloud. Even with tag in my search I got "it looks like" all of the cloud threads returned. Maybe we could start a thread on meta to discuss. Or maybe it doesn't bother anyone else. ???

Comment: Could you simply create the wordle image and apply a clip boundary? ie does it matter if words get chopped or truncated at the edges?

Comment: @Mark I guess you mean using a "mask". I was thinking of that at some point, but if you look at the examples given on http://www.wordle.net you will soon see that depending on the No. words and their relative frequencies you will get tag clouds of varying shape. As a consequence, it is likely that cropping will have a disastrous effect on the final output. Another option would be to apply some kind of warping (this is the way I think I would go actually) as done with functional neuroimaging data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would take very little tweaking: approximate the polygon boundary by isothetic lines (that is, horizontal and vertical segments) and, as initial conditions, place boxes (with blank content) aligned along those lines in the *exterior* of the polygon and in the interior of the polygon's bounding box.  At this point the configuration would look exactly as if the Wordle algorithm had been going for a while and had happened to place the first words around the perimeter of the bounding box.  Let the algorithm take over from there.

In effect, this amounts to representing the polygon with a quadtree from the outset and otherwise exactly reproducing the Wordle algorithm.

If you're not placing thousands of words into the polygon and if you have a little computing time to spare, you don't have to code a spatial index at all: you can perform collision detection using brute-force all-pairs comparisons of the bounding boxes.  With a tiny bit more work you can maintain lists of the word locations sorted by x- and y-coordinates and exploit these lists to streamline the collision detection algorithm.

Answer (score 6):

Very trick. I'm trying to do something like that myself, but to produce typographic maps like [this](http://www.axismaps.com/typographic.php) one from Axis Maps.

[image]

You can try something with qgis or mapnik, the basics would be:
1)Count the words and generate a weight by the number of occurrences.
2)generate random points inside a poligon.
3)for each point upload a word and it's weight to attibute table.
4)Draw the text with font size based on the weight.

You can also add a random rotation and colors to the table.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for pointing out typographic maps. It reminds me that I came across cool stuff some months ago. I'll give it a try but I was wondering whether the available Python code contributed by [@aeby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342687/algorithm-to-implement-something-like-wordle/3394601#3394601) on SO would not be helpful too, providing I add contraints on country boundaries. I'm not familiar enough with QGis but I will try to learn it.

Comment: Placing words at uniformly random points will generally produce many overlaps.  If the words are uniformly scaled to almost fill the polygon--which in most cases is the desirable situation--then using random points is certain not to work.  It would be a good start for a spatial simulated annealing algorithm, though :-).

Comment: They wont overlap because qgis and mapnik have collision detectors. But some words will be suppressed. There are many other problems, like, how many words would you need depending on the polygon size?

Comment: @whuber, Following your ideia, Maybe instead of random points, the algorithm may start filling the polygon with other polygons with the word size from top left until botton right. then label these polygons.

Answer (score 5):

[Tagxedo](http://www.tagxedo.com/) looks good. Too bad it uses Silverlight.

Comment: (+1) Looks good, though it would be best not to rely on Silverlight.

Answer (score 3):

This might be useful: [A Constructive Genetic Approach to Point-Feature Cartographic Label Placement](http://www.lac.inpe.br/~lorena/mic2003/chapter-yamamoto-lorena.pdf).