# Word cloud labels in QGIS from database

Tags: qgis, labeling, database, word-cloud

I would like to do some word clouding as labels in QGIS from a series of tables in a database. Examples of word clouds can be found here: [Word Cloud - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=word+cloud&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=QXkHVN65FJD-yQSiwoDQCQ&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1676&bih=754&dpr=0.75)

I have two tables in a database: locations and codes. The locations are cities that have geometry. The codes are the words I would like to use as labels. I have a count with the codes, which I hope to use as text font size.

Does anyone know if there is a way to label in QGIS from a related table. I have drawn a schema and example of what I would like to achieve.

Any thoughts are welcomed.

[image]

Comment: Nothing specific to QGIS, but a couple of other similar questions are [Fitting a word/tag cloud into geographic boundaries](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5720/fitting-a-word-tag-cloud-into-geographic-boundaries) and [How to create spatial tag clouds or “tag maps”](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4366/how-to-create-spatial-tag-clouds-or-tag-maps).  You can find these and other similar questions by searching "tag + cloud".

Comment: Ryan (Garnett) - what diagrammer are you using in that screen shot?

Comment: @mapBaker I used a collection of software to make that. The schema/table relationship was made with Navicat Data Modeler. The map graphic was made with QGIS, and the text and "put-togetherness" was finalized in Inkscape. I would be great if there was a method, or better a tool to do all of this in QGIS.

Comment: @RyanGarnett do you know of a good open source postgresql database modeler? QGIS would companion well with a system like that... pgModeler is no longer free, but it is awesome!

Comment: @mapBaker no I do not know if a good PostgreSQL modeler